# javascript document. getElementById('').value returns null

Tags: javascript, null, settimeout, getelementbyid

If I directly insert the method `document.getElementById` in the method `setTimeout` it works fine

1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>


function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, document.getElementById("numbers").value);
}
</script>
<input id="numbers" type="textbox"  />
</body>
</html>
```

2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

var numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, numbers);
}
</script>
<input id="numbers" type="textbox"  />
</body>
</html>
```

Why the second one doesn't work? I think that the `var numbers` returns `null`, but I don't know why.

Comment: Because the JavaScript code runs before the `<input>` is part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version you are retrieving the element and its value when the click event fires and calls the attached handler. In that moment the input field has a value which is returned.

In the 2nd version you are retrieving the input element and its value when the input field does not exists in the DOM, thus  `null` is used when the handler is called. Obviously you should go for the former.

Comment: Script tags do not validate outside of the `<body>` or `<head>` tags.  The best place to put this script would probably be right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The line `var numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value` is being executed on the load of your page, `numbers` does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

Like @gmiley has said, numbers doesn't exist it yet. You should include:

```
var numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value
```

inside of your function.

Also, on a side note...It's probably not best to put your javascript in the middle of the file. I almost didn't see the 'input' after the 'script' tags.